# rails syntax (rails generate etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I can't seem to find a reference to what I am trying to do.

```
rails generate model Example number:integer
```

or

```
rails generate model Example number:int
```

And when generating a migration is it possible to add multiple attributes in a single migration? The only ones I have seen are like this:

```
rails generate migration add_something_to_users something:string
```

I would like to add multiple attributes like so

```
rails generate migration add_economy_stats_to_state gdp:integer total_imports:integer
```

I've tried it a few ways but seem to run into errors so though if I could clarify the syntax I am supposed to use then it's just a case of being more careful when I type in commands.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#model-generators) is description of Rails model generator. What kind of error do you have?

Comment: Found the needed syntax and it seems to be `decimal` that is required instead of `integer` so thank you very much. The problems I was having were 1) I didn't know if I have to use `integer` or `int` or `decimal` to save a number in the database and 2) wasn't sure if you can add multiple attributes in a single migration.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example should have worked in current Rails, you should check your Rails and Ruby versions.  I have seen references to the Magical Columns back to Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3.

I am running Rails 4.1.6 on Ruby 2.1.2 and it worked for me as below:

```
rails generate model Product name:string description:text counter:integer
```

Here is a reference to the Rails Guides page that describes it:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

There is also an example there for adding multiple magic columns using the command line rails 'generate migration ...' syntax.

Comment: It uses two examples. 1) `t.change :price, :integer` and 2) `rails generate migration AddDetailsToProducts part_number:string price:decimal` so whats the difference between `rails generate model Product name:string description:text counter:decimal` and `rails generate model Product name:string description:text counter:integer`

Comment: @Jonathan As a side note, if you want to experiment and see the difference for yourself, you can generate the model as you described, and then destroyed it afterwards using `rails destroy model Product` (which will also clear up all the other files generated along with it).

Comment: @Jonathan The difference between the two is the SQL datatype of the column counter.  In most databases an Integer is a two's compliment binary number and a decimal is a fixed precision number represented by a string of numerical characters.  The difference is how they are stored internally in the DB and the calculation precision.